# Break lines in the output of chunks' code & results in rmarkdowns' beamer

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown, chunks, beamer

**Problem:**
I am preparing [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/)-slides using [`beamer_presentation`](https://garrettgman.github.io/rmarkdown/beamer_presentation_format.html)-output format for a workshop and want to break long lines in the output of chunks' codes & results.

There are *four sub-problems* that need to be solved:
[image]

1. Long **contiguous** string in chunks' **code** output

   *like:* `savepage("https://www.bundestag.de/webarchiv/Ausschuesse/ausschuesse19/a07/Anhoerungen")`
2. Long **non-contiguous**  string in chunks' **code** output

   *like:* `system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)`
3. Long **contiguous**  string in chunks' **result** output

   *like:* `"https://www.bundestag.dehttps://www.bundestag.de/resource/image/244626/2x3/316/475/b16fd9b7ae2fc1b1e097c016394bdcb6/ie/default.jpg"`
4. Long **non-contiguous**  string in chunks' **result** output

   *like:* `[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<meta charset="utf-8"> ...`

---

**What I already tried:**

A. [This](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/) solves none of the four sub-problems:

````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy=TRUE,tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60))
```
````

B. The solutions suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54946/how-to-break-a-long-url) should tackle sub-problems 1 & 3 but do not work either (works only for strings within the command url()):

```
header-includes: 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
or
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-\do?}
or
\usepackage[T1,hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

C. The solution suggested [here](https://coderedirect.com/questions/362941/textwrapping-long-string-in-knitr-output-rstudio) solves sub-problem 3 only for predefined strings

````
```{r break}
str_break = function(x, width = 80L) {
  n = nchar(x)
  if (n <= width) return(x)
  n1 = seq(1L, n, by = width)
  n2 = seq(width, n, by = width)
  if (n %% width != 0) n2 = c(n2, n)
  substring(x, n1, n2)
}
x = paste(sample(c('A', 'C', 'T', 'G'), 1000, replace = TRUE), collapse = '')
str_break(x)
```
````

D. This solves **sub-problem 2**:

```
header-includes: 
\usepackage{fvextra}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
```

E. This addresses **sub-problem 4** but throws an error:

```
header-includes: 
\usepackage{fvextra}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
---
Error: 
! Undefined control sequence.
    <argument> ## [1] <head>\n 
                               <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/htm...
    l.13 ...ype" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 ...
        #\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
```

---

**Looking forward:**

- I think the scope of attempt D must be extended to contiguous strings (sub-problem 1)
- ... and the error in attempt E have to be fixed and also extended to contiguous strings (sub-problem 3)

---

**Minimal working example:**

The sub-problems are shown on the "Sub-problem 1", "Sub-problem 2", ... slides.

The code may have to be executed more frequently in order to open the website (I have not yet been able to solve this phenomenon).

````
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_md: true
    keep_tex: no
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
#enable line breaks in chunks
  - |
    \usepackage{fvextra}
    \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
#   \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
if(!require("tidyverse")) install.packages("tidyverse") 
  library(tidyverse) # for fill() 
if(!require("formatR")) install.packages("formatR")
  library(formatR)
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = T,
                      eval = T)
```

```{r Selenium, include=F}
if(!require("RSelenium")) install.packages("RSelenium")
library(RSelenium)
if(!require("rvest")) install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest) #for read_html(), html_elements()...
#Free all ports
  system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
#Start a selenium & Assign client to an R-object  
  rD <- rsDriver(port = 4561L, browser = "firefox")
  remDr <- rD[["client"]]
```

```{r define_savepage, include=F}
#Load url & return content as r-object 
  savepage <- function(url){
    #Navigate to starting page
      remDr$navigate(url)
    #Wait until page is loaded  
      Sys.sleep(abs(rnorm(1, 2, 1)))
    #Save content to an R-object
      remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>%  
        read_html() %>% 
        return()
  }
```

# Sub-Problems
```{r problems1-2, results='hide'}
#Sub-problem 1
page <- savepage("https://www.bundestag.de/webarchiv/Ausschuesse/ausschuesse19/a07/Anhoerungen")
#Sub-problem 2
system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```
```{r problems3-4}
#Sub-problem 3
html_element(page, xpath="//meta[10]") %>%
  html_attr("content")
#Sub-problem 4
html_element(page,xpath="//meta[3]")
```
````

Comment: Could you use Beamer presentation with HTML output? I think you would have better luck if you made your question more simple and reduced. Have you tried `\linebreak` for a line break?